# How to load external script in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an external javascript file that I've placed in `vendor/`. In my ember-cli-build.js file, I import the script:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app')

module.exports = function (defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // options
  })

  app.import('vendor/myscript.js')

  return app.toTree()
}
```

When I run the app I get this warning:
`Warning: ignoring input sourcemap for vendor/myscript.js because ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/project/root/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-SmgGJJq3.tmp/0/vendor/myscript.js.map'`

Why is it searching for the script in `/tmp`?

Comment: try removing `tmp` folder ( `rm -rf tmp`) and also double check myscript.js file exists in vendor folder

Answer (score 1):

It was searching in `tmp` because Ember stores there some of the output files. It looks like during concatenation `myscript.js` file was not found. Are you sure that you put the file in the main folder (`/vendor`), not `/app/vendor`?

Comment: Note: default folder name is `vendor` not `vendors`